# how to copy form fields from one form to another on checkbox tick?

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a form for an address and a form for another address, both forms have the same fields.

When one form is filled, I want the user to be able to check a box to copy the form data over to the other form as these will be the same values most of the time.

I have all the text fields working, I'm just stuck with the dropdown menu for country and province.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
function FillShipping(f){ if(f.shippingtoo.checked == true)
{
  {
    f.email1.value = f.email.value;
    f.fullName1.value = f.fullName.value;
    f.address1.value = f.address.value;
    f.address3.value = f.address2.value;
    f.city1.value = f.city.value;
    f.postCode1.value = f.postCode.value;
    f.phone11.value = f.phone1.value;
    f.phone22.value = f.phone2.value;
    f.phone33.value = f.phone3.value;
    f.cell11.value = f.cell1.value;
    f.cell22.value = f.cell2.value;
    f.cell33.value = f.cell3.value;
  }
}
else
{
    f.email1.value = '';
    f.fullname1.value = '';
    f.address1.value = '';
    f.address3.value = '';
    f.city1.value = '';
    f.postCode1.value = '';
    f.phone11.value = '';
    f.phone22.value = '';
    f.phone33.value = '';
    f.cell11.value = '';
    f.cell22.value = '';
    f.cell33.value = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming your country and province combo names are `country`, `province`, `country1` and `province1`):

```
f.country1.selectedIndex = f.country.selectedIndex;
f.province1.selectedIndex = f.province.selectedIndex;
```

Comment: Tiago, you're AWESOME. Thank you so much, have a nice weekend.